# Interpolate points to lines every odd and even number

Tags: interpolation, oracle-spatial

We are working in Oracle Database 11g. There is a table with sdo_geomerty column(representing a line) which contains the following :

```
RSID,       LT,      LF,      GEOM
584908,     30,      34,      [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] 
1312994,     1,      9,       [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]
```

In the column of geom is the MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY there are more than 2 points with known coordinates, so we can say that is a curve too.
For the 2 records above, we want to compute the coordinates for the points placing at the even and odd intervals correspondingly.

To be clear, for the first record we want the point coordinates in 30,32,34.
For the second record we want the point coordinates in 1,3,5,7,9.
The start and end of each line is known as we can extract the first and last pair of coordinates from geometry column.
I am looking for a program logic (I am working on these languages C#, Python, pL SQL) that combines the Pythagorean theorem and the relations between Polar and Rectangular Coordinates to find the coordinates at even intervals when the edges of the line are even and odd numbers correspondingly.
These numbers are street road numbers and the lines depict the road network.

Visit http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math4c/textbook/chapter9/polar_coordinates.htm

I have good knowledge on plsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it looks like you need something similar to dynamic segmentation. I have written a small series of posts on this a while back. Have a look at [Part 2](http://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/oracle-spatial-for-the-thrifty-developer-part-2-calculating-line-lengths-and-more/) and [Part 3](http://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/oracle-spatial-for-the-thrifty-developer-part-3-the-basics-of-dynamic-segmentation/) to see if they help.